# How to organize data correctly by the sum of fields from another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The `games` table has `counters`. There may be several of them. the `counters` have a field `sent:bigint`.
How to sort the `games` in asc order by the count of sent counters?

**Company #1** has two counters. one has a `sent=3`, the other has `sent=2`, there are 5 sent counters in total.
**Company #2** has 1 counter. it has the value `sent=4`.

that is, if you make the order in ascending order, then it should turn out like this: `company 2, company 1`

my code:

```sql
SELECT games.*, counters.game_id 
FROM games INNER JOIN counters 
ON games.id = counters.game_id 
GROUP BY counters.sent 
ORDER BY sum(counters.sent) asc
```

Comment: Can you share you tables definitions and some simple data

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're ordering by the value of `sent` when you've specifically said that you only care about the number of `counters` a game has rather than the value of `sent` in `counters`

So unless I am misunderstanding your question, the below query answers the following:

"Retrieve all rows in `games` such as `games` has `counters` ordered by the total number of `counters` a game has in ascending order.

```
select g.* 
  from games g, counters c 
  where g.id = c.game_id
  group by c.game_id
  order by count(c.game_id) asc;
```